# Django: include get_absolute_url() in abstract model?

Tags: python, django, url, django-models, abstract-class

I'm working on a project that allows the user to fill in and save checklists needed in gastronomy.
As the checklists' content differ from one another, I decided to create an abstract base class 'checklists' with shared fields and have child models for differing attributes.

I want to find a way to dynamically create unique urls for each checklist through the abstract model. 
The only way I can make it work so far is to include a get_absolute_url() in each child model - but this way I have to manually define a url in my urlpatterns and different views for each child model. Feels like unnecessary repetition.

I tried including the get_absolute_url() in my abstract model. However, this does not work because I can't seem to access the child's attributes in the abstract model.
Is there a way to include get_absolute_url() in my abstract base class?

I appreciate your help! Thanks a lot!

This is part of the code:

models.py

```
class Checklisten(models.Model):
    # abstract model that contains shared features of all checklists

    erlaubte_pruefer = models.ForeignKey(Pruefer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    verbose_name='Prüfer')
    pruefende_firma = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Unternehmen')
    raum_verbindung = models.ManyToManyField(Raeume, verbose_name='Ort')
    datum = models.DateField('Datum', auto_now_add=True, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datum', 'pruefende_firma', 'raum_verbindung', 
        'erlaubte_pruefer']
        abstract = True
        verbose_name = 'Checkliste'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Checklisten'

        # can I include a get_absolute_url() with pk, datum AND a abbreviated 'bezeichnung' here?

class Checklisten_Schaedlinge(Checklisten):

    insekten_befall = models.BooleanField('Insektenbefall', default=False)
    befall_art = models.CharField('Insektenart des Befalls', blank=True, 
    null=True, max_length=40)
    bezeichnung = 'Schädlingsmonitoring/Bekämpfung'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Schädlingsmonitoring/Bekämpfung'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Schädlingsmonitoring/Bekämpfung'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.datum, self.bezeichnung)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('checkliste-detail', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk,
                                              'datum' : self.datum})


class Checklisten_Waagen_Thermometer(Checklisten):

    WAAGE = 'WA'
    THERMOMETER = 'TH'

    ART = (
        (WAAGE, 'Waage'),
        (THERMOMETER, 'Thermometer')
    )

    werkzeug_art = models.CharField('Art', choices=ART, default=WAAGE, 
    max_length=40)
    geeicht = models.BooleanField('geeicht', default=False)
    naechster_eichtermin = models.DateField('Nächster Eichtermin')
    bezeichnung = 'Erfassungsliste Waagen & Thermometer'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Erfassungsliste Waagen & Thermometer'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Erfassungslisten Waagen & Thermometer'

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s'%(self.datum, self.bezeichnung)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('checkliste-waage', kwargs={'pk' : self.pk,
                                              'datum' : self.datum})
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('meine-checklisten/schaedlinge/<pk>/<datum>/, views.Checklisten_Schaedlinge_Detail_View.as_view(), name='checkliste- 
        schaedlinge'),
        path('meine-checklisten/waagen/<pk>/<datum>/', views.Checklisten_Waagen_Detail_View.as_view(), name='checkliste- 
        waage'),]
```

views.py

```
class Checklisten_Schaedlinge_Detail_View(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Checklisten_Schaedlinge
    template_name = 'checklisten/checkliste-schaedlinge-detail.html'

class Checklisten_Waagen_Detail_View(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Checklisten_Waagen_Thermometer
    template_name = 'checklisten/checkliste-schaedlinge-detail.html'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. You certainly can access attributes in the super class, eg `self.pk` and `self.datum`. But defining the method there won't remove the need for defining a URL pattern for each model if you want separate views.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Daniel Roseman. I am aware that I can access pk and datum as they are part of the abstract model. But what if I want to include 'bezeichnung' in get_absolute_url? This is only in the child's classes.

Comment: But it is the child classes that will be calling the method. It doesn't make any difference where the attribute is defined.

Comment: You're right, thanks! But it is also true that I won't have enough control over the views if I don't define one for each model. Thanks for helping me out!